# Success Criteria 1.4.3 Contrast (Minimum) (AA) problem, can't change the color codes in additional CSS or style.css

Tags: css, wordpress, contrast, wcag2.0

Greeting to all the members of this great community and thank you in advance for your time!
I have a site from a client I have to make wcag 2.0 AA compliant. I'm quite a newbie I should note and at the moment I'm stuck at several Success Criteria 1.4.3 Contrast (Minimum) (AA) errors. The site is http://www.autosinidisia.gr/ and for example I'm getting this error:

Line 108, Column 9:

Νικολόπουλος Αριστομένης: Ψυχολόγος Καλα ...
Fixed size example: color contrast example

Real size example (10.61 points): color contrast example

CSS rules for the element:

```
External CSS (http://www.autosinidisia.gr/wp-content/themes/medica-lite/style.css?ver=1.3):

   

    body{
    
                background:#f3f3f3;
                color:#fff;
                font-size:14px;
                font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif;
          }
    
     div{
    
                html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
```

etc etc

So my first guess was to try change the color code for background both in Additional CSS and directly on the appropriate style.css file but in vain, everytime I check again the site through the achecker.ca, the color code is unchanged. Also I have to note that the site is not created be me and it uses phpmyadmin panel that I'm completely unfamilliar with so for example I can't create a child theme because I have no idea where to find the wp-themes folder in there but that's another topic and I guess I'll have to create a new topic for that if it's gonna  be needed. Sorry for the parenthesis. Please anybody have a clue what I should do, it will be greatly appreciated because I feel very stuck atm! Please notify me for any wrongs I have in my post because it's been a long time since I have visited the community. Thanks in advance and have a great day for everyone!

Edit: I'd try to add some more clues as I can. First, I forgot to mention that the page uses the Medica Lite theme. Also I checked the errors and I see that there doesn't seem to be an actual contrast problem, take a look at this for example:

Line 370, Column 12:

Ανάπτυξη αυτοπεποίθησης μέσα από τον αυτοδιαλογο Η α ...
Fixed size example: color contrast example

Real size example (10.61 points): color contrast example

CSS rules for the element:

```
External CSS (http://www.autosinidisia.gr/wp-content/themes/medica-lite/style.css?ver=1.3):
```

#content{

```
        width:100%;
        background:#fff;
        padding:60px 0px;
        float:left;
  }
```

body{

```
        background:#f3f3f3;
        color:#fff;
        font-size:14px;
        font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif;
  }
```

p{

etc, etc

But looking actually at the text element in question there (Ανάπτυξη αυτοπεποίθησης μέσα από τον αυτοδιαλογο, sorry it's in greek) doesn't seem to be any contrast problem:

[contrast problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHiHO.png)

Also there is a reset.css file, does it play any role about this? Thank you all guys and sorry for the trouble, if the information I shared are not helpful enough to track the problem, I will contact the Medica Lite developers to ask for  help. Take care all!

Comment: The heading text is `#42b3e5` and the background is white (`#fff`). Running this through [the webaim colour contrast checker](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=42B3E5&bcolor=FFFFFF) it only gets a contrast of 2.38:1. You should be aiming for 3:1 contrast on large text as a minimum. If you right-click and then inspect the element you can actually click on the `colour: #42b3e5` entry in the styles panel and it shows the contrast ratio there. It also gives you a colour picker so you can fiddle with the colour until you have sufficient contrast. Line 782 in your CSS file.

Comment: Graham thank you so much for your reply! All you said is very helpful but unfortunately, as I stated before, I can't see a way to change these color values. If I do so either through additional CSS or in the styles.css file and then load the page and the achecker.ca again, the color is still unchanged. I tried to add a code in additional CSS to change full-header.content and h3 where I see the colors you mentioned but nothing happened, I also edited them in the styles.css file, the same, nothing changed. Could you help me finding the additional CSS code I need to write? Thank you again bro!

Comment: /wp-content/themes/medica-lite/style.css is the location of the file as you stated, but in the question you are on about a completely different line to the one you need to fix. It is line 782, you are looking for `#content #latest-news .news .info-news a {` - the `color: #42b3e5` is not dark enough, use the colour contrast checked I linked and find a colour with 4.5:1 contrast ratio that is similar and then replace the hash value with the new colour. If you have already done this and the style.css file is not updating you may have a cache plugin that needs clearing.

Comment: Thank you again so much Richie, you are very helpful, the thing is I believe I changed the colors at last to a dark blue with 6.46:1 contrast ratio but the errors still show up the same, maybe I should try to contact the Theme developers?

Comment: You have fixed the article titles! It is now complaining about the main menu (as it is the same colour as the old headers) and your dates in the articles (as they are just a little bit too light). I think perhaps you just didn't notice that the errors were different as the article title is just above the date. If you fix the menu background colour and the dates I think that is all the colour contrast issues (maybe the button in the "hero" section at the top will also need a darker background)

Comment: Richie, thanks again soooo much!!! I'm sorry for the late reply, didn't have the chance to look at it yet because I had some more urgent jobs these days, I'm going to check it now and reply to you,  God bless you mate, you are really helpful!

Comment: Finally my brain "started to work" I guess and suddenly it fell to only 4 errors compared to the 33 before, so I'm sure I'm close to finish! Graham I can't thank you enough, please tell me how I can upvote your answers because I don't see a way... Thanks a lot bro!

Answer (score 0):

so I'm able now to change most of the colors thanks to you, at last I tried to change the dates color using the code:

```
#content #latest-news .news .info-news a {
    color: #000000;
}
```

because I figured through inspector that this is the line I had to change but in fact the color of the header changed only. Do you know why? The errors are still here but I believe when I finish with the changes it will be alright. BTW are you using achecker.ac or some other tool? You have already provided me a ton of help and the least I can do is to thank you truly for all the time and the quality answers you offered me!